# Retrieve Matplotlib 3D surface projection to 2D view

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to do raycasting/triangulation to a 3D surface that has shadowing (i.e. parts that are occulted by a front face of the surface) and decide which surface comes closest for each image pixel. I've seen that the mplot3d does this quite fast, but I can't find the proper way to retrieve the closest surface.

Currently I'm doing this using Fortran. I'm making a triangulation of the surface points, casting a ray on each image pixel and deciding which surface comes closest to the screen view. Even though this works, Matplotlib seems to do it much faster when, for example, I plot the surface using plot_trisurf().

I've read questions in the forum and Matplotlib documentation. However, I can't find the proper way to retrieve the 2D view using the built-in instances of a Poly3DCollection. This would be very useful for my code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.